# Android gridview and custom header

Tags: android, gridview

I'm struggeling implementing the following GUI:

[image]

For the 9 elements below the redline (everything under the line should be scrollable) I used a gridview layout which is working as intented. But actually I have no Idea how I make the Header.

My xml so far:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
   android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
   android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
   android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
   android:background = "@drawable/t"
   tools:context=".AppStarter" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="center">
    <GridView 
        android:id="@+id/gridview"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:numColumns="3"
        android:verticalSpacing="10dp"
        android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
        android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginLeft="2sp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5sp"
        android:layout_marginTop="0sp" />
 </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

My Idea was to add an additional linearLayout over the gridview, but the this approach didn't deliver the expected results. Any Ideas how I could implement this header?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4):

You can try my own implementation. After many tries I decided write my own code!

https://github.com/munix/GridViewHeader

Answer (score 0):

You can use a Horizontal LinearLayout for the header and use the parent RelativeLayout to position the GridView below it:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
   android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
   android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
   android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
   android:background = "@drawable/t"
   tools:context=".AppStarter" >

   <!-- Header section -->
   <LinearLayout
       android:id="@+id/headerlayout" 
       android:layout_width="match_parent" 
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:orientation="horizontal" >

           <!-- Example header content -->
           <FrameLayout 
               android:id="@+id/frame1"
               android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
               android:layout_height="match_parent" />

           <FrameLayout 
               android:id="@+id/frame2"
               android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
               android:layout_height="match_parent" />

   </LinearLayout>

   <!-- GridView section -->
   <GridView 
       android:id="@+id/gridview"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_below="@id/headerlayout" <!-- This line sets relative position of GridView -->
       android:numColumns="3"
       android:verticalSpacing="10dp"
       android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
       android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
       android:gravity="center"
       android:layout_marginLeft="2sp"
       android:layout_marginRight="5sp"
       android:layout_marginTop="0sp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: This is not a header because the header should be scrolled up when you scroll the gridView